# Multiple condition IF statement to proceed to next userform

Tags: vba

The idea is to have a userform with two textboxes, one for a lower number (textbox.10) and one for a higher number (textbox.11).

When the user inputs these values, he/she gets transferred to the next userform.

Both numbers must be inside the range 0-100 and the lower number needs to be lower than the higher.

```vb
If TextBox10.Value <= 0 Or TextBox10.Value >= 100 Or TextBox10.Value >= TextBox11.Value Or TextBox11.Value <= 0 Or TextBox11.Value >= 100 Then

    MsgBox "Error!" & vbCrLf & "Instructions: Both numbers must be higher than 0 and less than 100" & vbCrLf & "Additionally, lower number cannot be higher than higher number and vice versa!" & vbCrLf & "Try again!"

    Exit Sub
       
Else
    UserForm4.Show
     
End If
```

Comment: Note `TextBox10.Value` reruns a string and not a number. You need to convert it with `CLng()` or `CDbl()`.

Answer (score 1):

So this was the correct code:

```
If IsNumeric(TextBox10.Value) And _
   IsNumeric(TextBox11.Value) And _
   Val(TextBox10.Value) > 0 And _
   Val(TextBox10.Value) < 101 And _
   Val(TextBox11.Value) > 0 And _
   Val(TextBox11.Value) < 101 And _
   Val(TextBox10.Value) <= Val(TextBox11.Value) Then
  
    UserForm4.Show
Else
    MsgBox "Error!" & vbCrLf & "Instructions: Both numbers must be higher than 0 and less than 100" & vbCrLf & "Additionally, lower number cannot be higher than higher number and vice versa!" & vbCrLf & "Try again!"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this **(not tested)**

```vb
If IsNumeric(TextBox10.Value) And _
   IsNumeric(TextBox11.Value) And _
   Val(TextBox10.Value) > 0 And _
   Val(TextBox10.Value) < 100 And _
   Val(TextBox10.Value) <= Val(TextBox11.Value) Then
  
    UserForm4.Show
Else
    MsgBox "Error!" & vbCrLf & "Instructions: Both numbers must be higher than 0 and less than 100" & vbCrLf & "Additionally, lower number cannot be higher than higher number and vice versa!" & vbCrLf & "Try again!"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Thank you mate, it worked out, I did some modification as seen below but your idea was correct!